# populate multiple select from mysql database prestashop

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, prestashop-1.5

I want to create a multiple select with add/remove button and the values in that multiple select i want to fetch from mysql query. my question is how will i populate the result of query in to select lists value?
my code is as follows: **Product.tpl**

```
         <form>
         <fieldset>
         <form name="formName1">
         <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5" >
         <option value="1?>">Item1</option>
         <option value="2">Item 2</option>
         <option value="3">Item 3</option>
         <option value="4">Item 4</option>
         </select>

         <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
         <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>

         <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
         <option value="5">Item 5</option>
         <option value="6">Item 6</option>
         <option value="7">Item 7</option>
         </select>
         <input type="button" onClick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
         </fieldset>
         </form>
```

and my php file code is :

```
       public function products_configure($url){
       $productsel = "Select id_product,name from ". _DB_PREFIX_ ."product_lang";
          $products = Db::getInstance()->executeS($productsel);
              foreach($products as $product){
                $productintid = $product['id_product'];
                $productintname = $product['name'];
                   }
                  $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                  'url' => $url
                   ));
              return $this->fetchTemplate('/views/templates/back/products.tpl');
               }
```

can anyone pls tell how will i use $productintname to option value in tpl file.